# Error using the clusGap function in R

Tags: r, cluster-computing

I want to determine the optimal number of clusters with R using the gap statistics in the following way

```
library(cluster)

clusGap(datamatrix, FUN=kmeans, K.max=10, B=10)
```

However I get the error

```
Error: could not find function "clusGap"
```

What does this mean? I have the cluster package because I can use the other functions. Was this function removed or do I do something wrong?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example otherwise you're question is very difficult to work with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had an old version of the cluster package.